# Why does a source transformation not work in this case?

Tags: resistors, current-source, thevenin, source, norton

[image][image][image: .]

Circuits 2 and 3 give 3.8 mA as the current through  R1 [2k Ohm resistor]. However, why is it not possible to transform circuit 3 to circuit 1?

what I did:
I tried simulating circuits 2 and 3 below to find the current through R1 resistor. Both circuits 2 and 3 give the same answer, 3.8 mA. However, if I transform the source from the last circuit to the first circuit the answer is different. Why is that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes. But you seem to have left them (5mA source and 2k resistor) alone.

Comment: Hi, I just made an edit to the question :), could you take a look at it again?

Comment: OK, show a third circuit where you have transformed that source & resistor so we can see how it looks.

Comment: please refer to resistors by name, not by value ... the top circuit contains multiple 2 k Ohm resistors

Comment: R2 in second figure is 500 ohm. Should it not be smaller than 100 ohm (R3 in first figure) ?

Comment: Yes,that was a typing error R3 should be 1k

Comment: 22V into 2k5. What's 'not to work' ?

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent circuit of the current source parallel to the 2k resistor is a 10V voltage source in series with a 2k resistor but it does not mean that we are speaking about the same physical resistor.

Exchanging these circuits gives a same behaviour vis-a-vis the external circuit.

Comment: Thank you, I suppose this means the information about internal behaviour is destroyed on transformation right

Comment: Exactly. Imagine the circuit to transform had many combined resistors and sources at the end you will get one source and one resistor which does not represent any part of the transformed circuit.

Comment: And if you are still confused and asking why in the upper circuit you have got the current you were expecting. It is because the current in the left two segments is almost the same and since the equivalent resistor is in series with the middle segment it is the latter current that you are getting.